# Display a grid using Canvas in Android

Tags: android, canvas, grid

I'm trying to display a grid in my Android application. I'm using the "onDraw" method of a custom view I created for this purpose.

The problem is that the result is very strange, not all lines are drawn and some artifacts are visible. May I have your help to solve this?

Here's the code I use:

```
public class GridView extends View {

    private int cellHeight;
    private int cellWidth;
    private int cellRows = 16;
    private int cellColumns = 16;
    private Paint lines = new Paint();

    public GridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public GridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public GridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        lines.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        lines.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        cellWidth = getWidth() / cellColumns;
        cellHeight = getHeight() / cellRows;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        cellWidth = getWidth() / cellColumns;
        cellHeight = getHeight() / cellRows;

        invalidate();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        for (int i = 0; i < cellRows; i++)
        {
            canvas.drawLine(0, i * cellHeight, getWidth(), i * cellHeight,
                    lines);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < cellColumns; i++)
        {
            canvas.drawLine(i * cellWidth, 0, i * cellWidth, getHeight(),
                    lines);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get in EMULATOR:
http://hpics.li/ca14cd1

Moreover, in Android preview (when designing activity), I can see the result expected:
http://hpics.li/7b97afb

The problem occurs when the application is really started.

Comment: It looks like the emulator doesn't give you the correct width and height. If you know the supposed width and height of the emulator screen, try replacing getWidth() and getHeight() with those values in your code to see if you still get the same results.

Comment: Indeed. I checked on a "true device" and the problem does not happen. Thanks !